# Shiny: Merge and filter uploads and export in excel format

Tags: r, shiny

I have these excel files.

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
state <- c("CA", "PA", "CA", "RA", "PA", "CA")
value <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600)
dat1 <- data.frame(id, state, value)
writexl::write_xlsx(dat1, "dat1.xlsx")


id <- c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66)
state <- c("PA", "CA", "PA", "RA", "CA", "PA")
value <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000)
dat2 <- data.frame(id, state, value)
writexl::write_xlsx(dat2, "dat2.xlsx")
```

What I want:

1. Upload these excel files.
2. Merge
3. Filter
4. Export the filtered dataset in Excel

The first two steps seems working. Here is what I have now,

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("exceldata1", "Data1", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx"),
    fileInput("exceldata2", "Data2", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx"),
    selectInput("selector", "State", choices = c("CA", "PA", "RA")),
    sliderInput("slider", "Value range",
                min = 100, max = 10000, value = c(100, 4000)),
    actionButton("dl", "Download")
    
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("combined")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  dat_1 <- reactive({
    req(input$exceldata1)
    inData1 <- input$exceldata1
    if (is.null(inData1)){return(NULL)}
    data1 <- readxl::read_excel(inData1$datapath)
  })
  
  dat_2 <- reactive({
    req(input$exceldata2)
    inData2 <- input$exceldata2
    if (is.null(inData2)){return(NULL)}
    data2 <- readxl::read_excel(inData2$datapath)
  })
  
  output$combined <- renderDT({
    
    merged <- bind_rows(dat_1(), dat_2())
    
  })
  

    output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.xlsx",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(merged(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I guess what I am missing is connecting the slider, selector to the merged dataset and download action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to guide me after step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the code is that `merged` is a local variable in the `renderDT()` function and is not accessible outside the function.

To fix this, you need to move the merged variable outside the `renderDT()` function and make it a reactive expression so it can be accessed outside the render function.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("exceldata1", "Data1", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx"),
    fileInput("exceldata2", "Data2", multiple = FALSE, accept = ".xlsx"),
    selectInput("selector", "State", choices = c("CA", "PA", "RA")),
    sliderInput("slider", "Value range",
                min = 100, max = 10000, value = c(100, 4000)),
    downloadButton("dl", "Download")
    
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("combined")
  )
  
))

server <- function(input,output,session){
  
  dat_1 <- reactive({
    req(input$exceldata1)
    inData1 <- input$exceldata1
    if (is.null(inData1)){return(NULL)}
    data1 <- readxl::read_excel(inData1$datapath)
  })
  
  dat_2 <- reactive({
    req(input$exceldata2)
    inData2 <- input$exceldata2
    if (is.null(inData2)){return(NULL)}
    data2 <- readxl::read_excel(inData2$datapath)
  })
  
  merged <- reactive({
    bind_rows(dat_1(), dat_2())
  })
  
  output$combined <- renderDT({
    merged()
  })
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(merged(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have got your suggestion. However, it is still not downloading the merged data. Anything else I am missing here?

Comment: Updated the answer it should work now. You have to use ```downloadButton``` function to create a download link or button instead of ```actionbutton```